# ClassCastException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagData.getAttributeString

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, taglib

My JSP code -

```
<c:set var="taskId" value="<%=someId%>" />    
<portlet:actionURL name="save" var="${taskId}_saveUrl" />
```

The above code throws class cast exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagData.getAttributeString(TagData.java:138)
```

I have tried following combinations but none seems to work

```
<portlet:actionURL name="save" var='<%= ${taskId} + "_saveUrl"%>' />

<portlet:actionURL name="save" var='<%= new String(${taskId} + "_saveUrl").toString()%>' />

<%String id = ${taskId} + "_saveUrl"; %>
<portlet:actionURL name="save" var="<%=id%>" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where your `someId` come from?

Comment: You can't put `<%= ... %>` inside attributes...

Comment: Is `someId` an Object?

Comment: Try `<portlet:actionURL name="save" var='<%= someId + "_saveUrl"%>' />` Don't mix JSP EL expression with Scriplet.

Comment: someId is 'String' object

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?